# "NAs introduced by coercion" in One-Class SVM using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, anomaly-detection, one-class

I am trying to perform a one-class SVM on my data set for anomaly detection. I keep getting a warning that "NAs introduced by coercion", which then does not allow me to fit my one-class SVM model because I subsequently get the error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed".

My data set has 18 variables (17 predictors and 1 dependent variable). Of the predictor variables, 15 of them are factors. I have a feeling that this is where the problem is coming from. My dependent variable is also a factor of 2 levels, but I don't think that should be an issue.

I have read that I should be able to use factors in SVM, but the R documentation says "If the predictor variables include factors, the formula interface must be used to get a correct model matrix." I really do not understand what this means.

This is the code I am using in R.

```
library(e1071)
impdata <- subset(data, select = c("Month","WeekOfMonth","MonthClaimed","WeekOfMonthClaimed",
                                   "MaritalStatus","Age","Fault","VehicleCategory","Deductible",
                                   "PastNumberOfClaims","AgeOfVehicle","AgeOfPolicyHolder",
                                   "AddressChange.Claim","BasePolicy","Sex","Days.Policy.Claim",
                                   "Year","Fraud")) #These are the features I am using in my model
impdata <- subset(impdata,  Fraud=="Yes")  
x <- subset(impdata, select = -Fraud)
y <- impdata$Fraud
model <- svm(x, y,type='one-classification')
```

This is the structure of my data:

```
'data.frame':   15419 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ Month              : Factor w/ 12 levels "Apr","Aug","Dec",...
 $ WeekOfMonth        : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",...
 $ MonthClaimed       : Factor w/ 12 levels "Apr","Aug","Dec",...
 $ WeekOfMonthClaimed : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",...
 $ MaritalStatus      : Factor w/ 4 levels "Divorced","Married",...
 $ Age                : int  21 34 47 65 27 20 36 32 30 42 ...
 $ Fault              : Factor w/ 2 levels "Policy Holder",...
 $ VehicleCategory    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Sedan","Sport",...
 $ Deductible         : int  300 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 ...
 $ PastNumberOfClaims : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2 to 4","more than 4",...
 $ AgeOfVehicle       : Factor w/ 8 levels "2 years","3 years",...
 $ AgeOfPolicyHolder  : Factor w/ 9 levels "16 to 17","18 to 20",...
$ AddressChange.Claim: Factor w/ 5 levels "1 year","2 to 3 years",...
 $ BasePolicy         : Factor w/ 3 levels "All Perils","Collision",..
 $ Sex                : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male"
 $ Days.Policy.Claim  : Factor w/ 3 levels "15 to 30","8 to 15",...
$ Year               : Factor w/ 3 levels "1994","1995",...
 $ Fraud              : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes"
```

Comment: Instead of using the `svm(x,y)` style of calling the function, use `svm(~., data = impdata, type='one-classification')`. Alternatively you could explicitly type out all the variables you want on the right-hand side of the tilde. `.` is just a shortcut to include everything in the data, in this context.

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen Thank you so much! This worked. Now I understand what formula interface means.